# Error in Ember when using multiple "with" statements

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In one of my templates I am using 2 with statements to render 2 different outlets

```
{{#with users as users}}
  {{outlet users}}
{{/with}}

{{#with admin.id as admin_id}}
  {{outlet admin}}
{{/with}}
```

I get this error:

```
Assertion failed: You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of [object Object])
```

However, if I change my code to:

```
{{#with users as users}}
{{#with admin.id as admin_id}}
  {{outlet users}}
  {{outlet admin}}
{{/with}}
{{/with}}
```

There is no error.

Comment: I think we'll need more context, I tried to replicate the basic setup without issue here, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/siyalotu/1/edit .  Also I'm not sure why you're wrapping an outlet with `with`, context of the outlet is built when you dynamically render into it.

Comment: @kingpin2k  I will try to get a small working example.  I forgot to mention that one of the outlets is a component and one is simply a template.  You are correct that the template does not actually need the #with statement